# ThreadSafeModule constructor strangeness

Tags: c++, llvm, unique-ptr, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to call an LLVM API that wants a `ThreadSafeModule` when I have a `Module*`. I look up `ThreadSafeModule` and it has these constructors:

```
ThreadSafeModule(ThreadSafeModule &&Other) = default;

/// Construct a ThreadSafeModule from a unique_ptr<Module> and a
/// unique_ptr<LLVMContext>. This creates a new ThreadSafeContext from the
/// given context.
ThreadSafeModule(std::unique_ptr<Module> M, std::unique_ptr<LLVMContext> Ctx)
    : M(std::move(M)), TSCtx(std::move(Ctx)) {}

/// Construct a ThreadSafeModule from a unique_ptr<Module> and an
/// existing ThreadSafeContext.
ThreadSafeModule(std::unique_ptr<Module> M, ThreadSafeContext TSCtx)
    : M(std::move(M)), TSCtx(std::move(TSCtx)) {}
```

The second or third seem suitable, so I try several variations:

```
ThreadSafeContext tsc;

ThreadSafeModule tsm(*module, tsc);
ThreadSafeModule tsm(module, tsc);
ThreadSafeModule tsm(std::move(*module), tsc);
ThreadSafeModule tsm(std::move(module), tsc);
auto tsm = new ThreadSafeModule(*module, tsc);
auto tsm = new ThreadSafeModule(module, tsc);
```

and the above with an `LLVMContext*` instead of a `ThreadSafeContext`, and in all cases I get basically the same error message:

```
jit.cpp(21): error C2664: 'llvm::orc::ThreadSafeModule::ThreadSafeModule(const llvm::orc::ThreadSafeModule &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'llvm::Module *' to 'std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'
    with
    [
        _Ty=llvm::Module
    ]
jit.cpp(21): note: Constructor for class 'std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' is declared 'explicit'
    with
    [
        _Ty=llvm::Module
    ]
```

The first part of the error message seems to be saying it is for some reason trying to call the copy constructor, but that seems to be contradicted by the next part.

Any idea what's going on with this, and what the correct incantation would be?

**Edit:**

Separate line for this works as far as it goes:

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> up(module);
```

But then this still fails:

```
ThreadSafeModule tsm(up, tsc);
```

with a slightly different error message:

```
jit.cpp(23): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    with
    [
        _Ty=llvm::Module
    ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\memory(2337): note: see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
    with
    [
        _Ty=llvm::Module
    ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\memory(2337): note: 'std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
    with
    [
        _Ty=llvm::Module
    ] (compiling source file jit.cpp)
```

Comment: The constructor wants a `std::unique_pointer<module>` not `module*`.  You will have to explicitly create a unique_pointer assuming `Module* module;`
something like `ThreadSafeModule tsm(std::unique_pointer(module), tsc);` might work (I haven't tested it)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Module>(module)` gives an error message 'attempting to reference a deleted function'

Comment: `make_unique(module)` gives an error message 'no matching overloaded function found'

Comment: Do you create `module`?  you could try `unique_ptr<Module> module = make_unique<Module>(args...)` instead of `Module* module = new Module(args...)`  I'm curious which method is deleted.  `make_unique` doesn't convert an exiting pointer into a unique pointer it creates a new pointer.

Comment: I don’t have a MCVE to test, but you might try `ThreadSafeModule tsm( std::unique_ptr<Module>(module), tsc );` if the default deleter is safe to use.  From the error messages, it looks to me as if there’s an incompatibility between MS and Google headers such that `std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module>` tries to call a function that `Module` explicitly deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to preejackie on #llvm for the answer: turns out the `unique_ptr` must be separately constructed and then moved:

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> up(module);
ThreadSafeModule tsm(std::move(up), tsc);
```

Comment: Ah! My suggestion from the comments no longer works in C++17 because prvalues are no longer moved from. In C++11, they were. You might still prefer `hreadSafeModule tsm( std::move(std::unique_ptr<Module>(module)), tsc );`as this is a little shorter and doesn’t leave behind a dangling unspecified `unique_ptr`.